# сохранение цикла

Tags: c#

Три цикла от 1 до 3. Необходимо сохранить данные в тхт, но не все данные. Должно быть так

```
1здесь_пробел1
здесь_два_пробела2
здесь_два_пробела3
2 1
  2
  3
3 1
  2
  3
```

но надо чтобы показывал так:

```
    1здесь_пробел1
    здесь_два_пробела2
    здесь_два_пробела3
    2 1
      2
      3
    3 1
      2
      3
```

Если с буквами `abc`
типа:
    aa
     b
     c
    ba
     b
     b
    ca 
     b
     c

Comment: «Необходимо сохранить данные» — какие данные? Как они относятся к трём циклам?

Comment: @VladD не много изменил вопрос, но в одной теме оба....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, самый короткий код, который выводит такие данные, у меня вот какой:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
        Console.WriteLine((j == 1 ? i.ToString() : " ") + " " + j);
```

Более читаемый вариант:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
{
    string main = " ";
    if (j == 1)
        main = i.ToString();
    main += " " + j;
    Console.WriteLine(main);
}
```

---

Для варианта со строкой можно, например, так:

```
string s = "abc";
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
        Console.WriteLine((j == 0 ? s[i] : ' ') + " " + s[j]);
```

или так:

```
string s = "abc";
foreach (var c1 in s)
{
    var prefix = c1;
    foreach (var c2 in s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prefix + " " + c2);
        prefix = ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: да, именно то что мне и надо было

Answer (score 1):

Посути тоже самое, но код глаза не режит.

```
int lenght = 4; //ограничение

for (int i = 1; i < lenght; i++)
{
   Console.Write(i + " ");
   for (int j = 1; j < lenght; j++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(j);
   }
}
```

Такой же вариант только с буквами

```
string ts = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char[] ar;
ar = ts.ToCharArray();
//Можно было сразу массив создать и не париться с лишней строкой, но я это для примера


int lenght = 4; //ограничение

for (int i = 1; i < lenght; i++)
{
   Console.Write(ar[i] + " ");
   for (int j = 1; j < lenght; j++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ar[j]);
   }
}

//Не забывайте что в lenght вы можете указать любое положительное число которое не больше колличества символов в алфавите.
```

Comment: а то что я дописал в вопросе, как сделать ?

Comment: не выходит то что надо:(

Comment: можете свою почту написать, а то тут не охота кое шо спрашивать...?

Comment: давай почту напиши)

Comment: пишите тогда вк)